# error :The argument type 'Set<Marker>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Set<Marker>

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

```dart
  onTap: widget.isSelecting ? _selectLocation : null,
          markers: (_pickedLocation == null && widget.isSelecting)
              ? null
              : {
                  Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId('m1'),
                    position: _pickedLocation ??
                        LatLng(
                          widget.initialLocation.latitude,
                          widget.initialLocation.longitude,
                        ),
                  ),
                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

either make `markers` nullable i.e `Set<Marker>? markers`

or

pass an empty Set instead of null, if this condition is true `(_pickedLocation == null && widget.isSelecting)`